# SQL select query returns the names of the columns

Tags: android, select, android-sqlite

I have a table which stores the ID (col_id), Name (col_name) and Username (username) of a user. Below is my codes I used to retrieve the data

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COL_DATA;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("col_id", KEY_ID);
        user.put("name", KEY_NAME);
        user.put("username", KEY_USERNAME); 
    }

    return user;
}
```

But when I log the retrieving data, it shows col_id, col_name and username instead of actual added data.

This is how I get the data and log it

```
dbHandler.setCollectorTable(colID, colName, username);
HashMap<String, String> tmpMap = dbHandler.getUserDetails();
Log.d("Retrieved Col ID", tmpMap.get(KEY_COL_ID));
Log.d("Retrieved Col Name", tmpMap.get("name"));
Log.d("Retrieved Col Username", tmpMap.get("username"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get Data from **Cursor** first. and then try to put data into `HashMap` like below:

```
 if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    user.put("col_id", cursor.getInt(0));
    user.put("name",cursor.getstring(1));
    user.put("username", cursor.getstring(2)); 
}
```

And go to [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html). There are many methods available for getting data from **Cursor** .